# How can I devide a class java into many classes?

Tags: java, class, user-interface

I have a main class with over 600 lines code :/ ! my app contains a toolbar,menubar and a field to draw a network nodes 
how can I devide my main class and what criteria to choose fo dividing ?

Comment: I'm not sure that this can be answered in the general sense, not without writing a book or book chapter.

Comment: [Possible duplicate questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+refactor+java+code+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F)

Comment: You could read about single responsibility principle. Cohesion metrics also could be great hint for splitting class into a few smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good evening,

if I understand your question well, I may advice you to read the "Clean Code " of Robert C.Martin. It is a great agile book, that can help your to divide your code.

Good luck

Comment: Thank's a lot :) Ill check it

Comment: You are most welcome . 
Good luck